# NoReverseMatch at /cart/ Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, rendering

Fellows I have an issue with this code, I'm trying to build a shopping cart but is not working, this is the error

```
NoReverseMatch at /cart/
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\user\Desktop\playzone\Playzoneshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
Python Executable:  C:\Users\user\Desktop\playzone\Playzoneshop\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\playzone\\Playzoneshop\\playzoneb',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\playzone\\Playzoneshop\\env\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\playzone\\Playzoneshop\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\playzone\\Playzoneshop\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Vie, 3 Jul 2020 02:28:59 +0000

Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\user\Desktop\playzone\Playzoneshop\playzoneb\templates\base.html, error at line 32

Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
22          <li class="nav-item">
23            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:login' %}">Ingresar</a>
24          </li>
25          <li class="nav-item">
26            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:logout' %}">Salir</a>
27          </li>
28          <li class="nav-item">
29            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:registro' %}">Registrarse</a>
30          </li>
31          <li class="nav-item">
32            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'carts:cart' %}">Carrito <span class="fas fa-shopping-car"></span></a>
33          </li>
34          
35        </ul>
36        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
37          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search">
38          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
39        </form> 
40      </div>
41    </nav>
42  </header>
```

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\user\Desktop\playzone\Playzoneshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\user\Desktop\playzone\Playzoneshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\user\Desktop\playzone\Playzoneshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\user\Desktop\playzone\Playzoneshop\playzoneb\carts\views.py in cart
        'cart': cart, …
▶ Local vars
```

**It says in the traceback the error is in line 10 in carts\views.py in cart, when I delete this line it renders the template**

*This are my Files*

**App carts urls.py file**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls', namespace='home')),
    path('cart/', include('carts.urls', namespace='carts')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Project urls.py file**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'carts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cart, name='cart'),
    path('agregar/', views.agregar_juego, name='agregar'),
]
```

**App cart views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from carts.models import Cart
from .utils import get_or_create_cart
from home.models import Juego

def cart(request):

    cart = get_or_create_cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart.html', {
        'cart': cart,
    })

def agregar_juego(request):
    cart = get_or_create_cart(request)
    juego = Juego.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('juego_id'))

    cart.games.add(juego)

    return render(request, 'agregar_carrito.html', {
        'juego': juego,
    })
```

**Base HTML file**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Play Zone Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="ico" type="image/png" href="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}">
</head>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Play Zone Shop</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:login' %}">Ingresar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:logout' %}">Salir</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:registro' %}">Registrarse</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'carts:cart' %}">Carrito <span class="fas fa-shopping-car"></span></a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
      </form> 
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

**cart HTML file**

```
% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load humanize %}

{% block content %}
                {% if cart.games.exists %}
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr >
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for juego in cart.games.all %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>{{ forloop.counter}}</th>
                                        <th>
                                            {% if juego.imagen %}
                                                <img src="{{juego.imagen.url}}" alt="Imagen producto" width="60" height="60">
                                            {% endif%}
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <a href="{% url home %}">{{juego.nombre}}</a>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>{{juego.existencia}}</th>
                                        <th><span class="font-weight-bold text-danger">{{juego.precio | intcomma }}</span>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <div class="col mt-4 pt-4 mb-4">
                        <p class="h3 mt-4 pt-4 mb-4">El carrito de compras está vacío.</p>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
    
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Wow... its so confusing with cart and carts... ????? Please check your post correctly if files and corresponding code actually reside there.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the app name is carts and the view is cart, I misspelled the app name